# Does thaumaturgy at "Evocation's Methods and Speed" inflict stress like Evocation does?

Tags: dresden-files, magic, stress

I have a character that has sponsored magic by 'The Power of Odin.'  One of Odin's aspects is travel.  I am wanting to make a 'Bamf' effect like Nightcrawler or Blink (Marvel superheros).  I decided against an actual instant portal into the Nevernever and out again, and opted for turning into the wind and moving very quickly to another location in the same zone.

Mechanically, I am just wanting to perform a brief maneuver (which is in the realm of thaumaturgy, think Entropy Curse) to place a temporary aspect on an opponent like **Where'd He Go**.

The real question is when I do this Thaumaturgical Sponsored Magic at "Evocation's Methods and Speeds," do I take the one mental stress as if it were evocation and do you have reference to that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you do take stress, because it is evocation (YS288, left side, 2nd bullet):

> The spell is cast like evocation: power first, control later, all done in one exchange

In the gathering phase of evocation you take mental stress according to the amount of power you want to use. (YS255, Gathering Power)